# Creating a dynamic scroll-down layout Facebook-style

Tags: android, facebook, layout

I'm trying to figure out how to make a non static layout like Facabook.
Basically when the user scrolls down on the activity he can't reach the end of the page because this one keep loading the videos that other users have uploaded in the past.

Something like Vines or Facebook.
I'm new to programming and a new user in stack overflow and I'd like to hear from more experienced users some suggestions/ideas or simply where to find the related material.

Deket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an endless scroll Listener, please take a look at this:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

just add this project to yours and use it like this:

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

            ... your asynchTask
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
        }
    });
```